# get list of objects and keep the object symbol as names

Tags: r

When making a list of objects, is there a way of keeping the object symbols to use them as names in the list?

The below uses `get` and re-assigns names afterwards, and I wondered if there is another approach.

```
a_1 <- 1
a_2 <- 2
a_3 <- 3

ls_a <-  lapply(ls(pattern = "a_"), get)
names(ls_a) <- ls(pattern = "a_")

ls_a

#> $a_1
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $a_2
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $a_3
#> [1] 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mget` has this as a default behavior.

```
mget(ls(pattern = "a_"))

#$a_1
#[1] 1

#$a_2
#[1] 2

#$a_3
#[1] 3
```